# How to migrate "as of timestamp" query in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5, temporal-tables

I want to migrate or write an equivalent query to get the data from table one hr before the current time in PostgreSQL.

oracle query:

```
select * 
from T_DATA as of timestamp (systimestamp - interval '60' minute);
```

Comment: There is no equivalent in Postgres. It does not support flashback queries

Comment: Right, you'll have to implement some kind of historization yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from T_DATA where timestamp_column >= now() - interval '1 hour'
```

Comment: That is something different. `as of` is a [flashback query](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6) in Oracle

Answer (score 0):

Since flashback queries are not supported in postgresql, One approach I tried with temporal tables extension.